# pandas sort column by correlation to first column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df

```
          A         B         C         D
A  1.000000  0.202557  0.689214  -.705000
B  0.202557  1.000000  0.038306 -0.113245
C  0.689214  0.038306  1.000000  0.074773
D  -.705000 -0.113245  0.074773  1.000000
```

I want to sort by correlation to column A,
should sort by positive to negative

```
          A         C        B         D
A  1.000000  0.689214  0.202557 -.705000
```

how can I do this?
Thanks

Comment: Does this help - `df.sort_values('A', ascending=False, axis=1)`?

Comment: What is in the DataFrame? Are those numbers correlation coefficients, or do you want to compute the correlation coefficients between columns and use those to sort?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I understand the question as follows: you have a dataframe, such as

```
   A  B  C
0  2  0  3
1  1 -3  0
2 -1  2 -2
3  3 -1  2
```

and want to sort its columns by the correlation to column A. This involves computing the correlation matrix (shown in the question) and then sorting the original dataframe according to the correlations. Here is how:

```
ix = df.corr().sort_values('A', ascending=False).index
df_sorted = df.loc[:, ix]
```

Output:

```
   A  C  B
0  2  3  0
1  1  0 -3
2 -1 -2  2
3  3  2 -1
```

The correlation matrix is symmetric, so I'm sorting in the direction pandas prefers, within columns instead of within rows. The index obtained is then used to reorder columns.